# How to remove react-router 2.0 warning about props.history?

Tags: react-router

I have a question about `ract-router` 2.0 migration in my React app.

I removed every mixin and calls to `this.props.history`, like explained in the migration guide, but I still have warnings about it in the console :

```
 Warning: [react-router] props.history and context.history are deprecated. Please use context.router
```

Actually, I found out in the debugger there is one warning for each nested component on the current page : `RouterContext`, `App`, and `Posts`

Any idea where it could come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug with RC4 and the React DevTools that come from the dev tools attempting to inspect all the props and context. This will be fixed in the new RC.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score -1):

You can disable this warning by going to `/node_modules/react-router/lib/RouterUtils.js` and commenting out lines 28-30.